# Type difference between "() => void" and "() => {}"

Tags: typescript

I'm playing with TS types, and when I define these ones:

```
type type1 = () => {}
type type2 = () => void
```

and create a variable to use the types:

```
const firstType: type1 = () => { }
const SecondType: type2 = () => { }
```

I'm getting the problem: `"Type 'void' is not assignable to type '{}'"` on the `firstType`.
Why is this happening? Both are "void" functions.

Comment: They're both void functions but that's the problem, `type1` doesn't describe a void function. `{}` (empty object) is not the same as `void` (nothing), it's not clear why you'd think it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
type type1 = () => {}
type type2 = () => void
```

The first declares a function type which returns `{}` i.e. the empty object

The second type is a function which returns void, i.e. nothing

---

In order to use the first type, you have to wrap the `{}` with brackets, otherwise typescript thinks you are missing a return statement

```
const firstType: type1 = () => ({})
const secondType: type2 = () => { }
```